# Error deploy NextJS14 app toVercel - Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Tags: node.js, typescript, next.js, vercel, next-auth

**Here is the problem:**
[image: image 1]

```
next: 14.1.4
next-auth: 4.24.7
node version: 20
```

**my structure auth folder:**
[image: image 2]

i got no error when run with `npm run dev`

i've research for this problem for three days, but i still stuck in it.
All i know that the problem cause by next-auth... but don't know how to resolve.
i just want deploy this for my Graduation Project.
Thank you for seeing this

Comment: Start by debugging the failing request. What does the server actually return?

Comment: @CherryDT it return entire the html document

Comment: What does your `next.config.mjs` look like?

Comment: @clxrity: just have remotePartterns for 3 host image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've resolved this problem by add

```
export const runtime = 'edge';
```

to my page.tsx
or remove <Suspense> component

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).